# How to export report files from Crystal Enterprise 10 server?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I am attempting to move some Crystal Reports from a legacy server (Crystal Enterprise 10) to their new home (SAP Business Objects XI v12). The former person in this position has multiple copies of reports everywhere with no versioning or documentation, so I decided to pull them all from the sources & start fresh.

In BO XI v12, to export a report file, I can select objects and choose "Send to --> File", which allows me to export the .rpt file.

However, in Crystal Enterprise 10, I can't discern any way to export the reports to a .rpt file. There doesn't seem to be anything in the CE 10 documentation referring to .rpt file export, either, so I'm thinking a philosophical shift occurred that I'm missing.

Any insight is appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To move objects and their instances (recurring or otherwise), you should use the Migration Wizard.  It will move large numbers of objects between servers and preserve their IDs.

You will need to do a client (i.e. not the services) installation of BusinessObjects Enterprise (BOE) to get this tool.

If you are just trying to publish a report to BOE, use the File | Save as... feature and choose 'Enterprise' from the vertical list.  The report's saved data will be discarded.

** edit **

To get a copy of the RPT w/ data to your workstation, there are a number of options:

1. schedule the report to a FTP location, to an 'unmanaged disk' (must be accessible by the Job Server), or email it to yourself
2. view the report "on demand' or a recently-scheduled instance, then use the Export button on the Viewer control to download the RPT w/ saved data.  You will need to have the 'Download files associated with the report' right, however.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for stepping up to help. All I'm looking to do is pull 7-8 reports from this version of Crystal into .rpt files that I can store on a hard drive and open later in the client software if necessary. Does the Migration Wizard allow for that?

Answer (score 0):

From the enterprise server you just need to render the report and export it from there.  It should have an option to save it in crystal report format.  Otherwise you can download it from the object explorer.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the help! If I render the report once and save it as an .rpt, will it save with my initially selected parameters as the default? Ideally, I think i'd like to download it from the Object Explorer, but I can't seem to find out how to do so; when viewing the list of objects, I have only "copy/move/shortcut" and nothing in the properties tabs for the object.

Comment: It will save the defaults so you will need to open it up and remove them and uncheck the 'Save Report Data' option to clear it all out.  I don't have access to enterprise server right now so I can't remember exactly what to click in object explorer but I know it can be done.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm looking for it everywhere. Is it accessible from the web interface? I'm using an account that I know has full admin permissions, but there are 100+ reports on a legacy server so of course I'd prefer not to run them individually just to get it to let me download .rpt files. :) been googling like mad, nothing so far.

Comment: Also interesting -- just realized I can't click the "Object Settings" button in Crystal, no matter what. This is the administrator account and it has full access to everything I can possibly give it access to as far as I can see. Not sure if that helps..